# Rails: Passing large number of params through query string

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I have a link 'on click' event handler that uses JS to get a list of the objects that are on the current page and then passes those through to the controller.

But the url is really long, and I'm wondering if there's another way to handle this. Here's the structure of the URL:

```
http://example.com/movies/dynamic?movie%5Btrailers%5D%5B%5D=rev5lBHlClQ&movie%5Btrailers%5D%5B%5D=cEUiW-JxCxU
```

For each additional object, I need to add:

```
&movie%5Btrailers%5D%5B%5D=XXXXXX
```

So the URL can get insanely long. In my rails view, I have a link:

```
<%= link_to "Click Here", :id=>"mashup"), "#" %>
```

Here's the JS:

```
 $('body').on('click', '#mashup', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var trailers = getAllTheTrailersOnThePage();
    var trailers_encoded = // some function that loops through all the trailers and turns them into a long query string

    var link = window.location.origin + "/mashups/dynamic?" + trailers_encoded
    window.location.href = encodeURI(link)
  });
```

This seems really dirty as the URL could become long with a huge number of params. It also seems really awkward to loop through everything and turn it into a url. How would I "hide" these params... or is there a better way to handle this?

Comment: use `POST` as url has limited length

Comment: So if I switch get to post, does the rest of my approach stay the same? How do I edit post params with JS?

Comment: you need to send a bunch of data from page to server, right? the only approach - grab this data and send it. Another question - do you actually need to send everything? it depends on your business logic

Comment: @Lashane basically there's a bunch of front-end filtering that the user can do, and then I want to give them the option to generate a dynamic page based on their sorting. There could potentially be some server-side workaround but I thought the simplest approach would be to grab the items they've filtered and pass them through